# separate unicode by commas in list

Tags: python, list, unicode, split

I have

```
[u'1,3,9,31,5,17']
```

I want

```
[u'1', u'3', u'9', u'31', u'5', u'17']
```

Is there is a function that can do this for me?
I have tried `self.plot_input.split(',')`but this doesn't work because `self.plot_input` is a list. Is there perhaps an alternative for `i.text()` that  gives me the desired output straight away?

```
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            data = []
            data.append(self.flist.item(index))                  
            self.plot_input = [i.text() for i in data]          #converting QListWidgetItem to list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you creating a list `data` with just one element? You can directly call `.split(',')` on the `self.flist.item(index).text()` and then store that in `self.plot_input` .

Example-

```
if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
    self.plot_input = self.flist.item(index).text().split(',')
```

Comment: cleanest method. I implemented this. :)

Comment: @leermeester Glad I could be helpful. I would like to advice you to accept answers for your question (All of the questions) , that would be really helpful for the community (and would give you 2 rep points for each accepted answer) .

Comment: great! Didn't know that feature

Answer (score 2):

It's a list with an element you can split. So use:

```
l = [u'1,3,9,31,5,17']
l[0].split(',')
```

Or if you have multiple elements you can use `chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(s.split(',') for s in [u'1,2,3', u'4,5,6']))
[u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6']
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
self.plot_input =[u'1,3,9,31,5,17']

self.plot_input [0].split(',')
```

will this work

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a1 = [u'1,3,9,31,5,17']
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, [s.split(',') for s in a1])
[u'1', u'3', u'9', u'31', u'5', u'17']
>>>
>>> a2 = [u'1,3,9,31,5,17', u'100,102']
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, [s.split(',') for s in a2])
[u'1', u'3', u'9', u'31', u'5', u'17', u'100', u'102']
```